# How to retrive which webview the JavascriptInterface is added to?

Tags: android, webview

To expose java methods to javascript, I used 
 `mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this),"Android");`

When I am actually in the JSInterface, how would I get the webview the JavascriptInterface was added to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are still dealing with the 2 webviews described here:
[How to handle callbacks in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659928/how-to-handle-callbacks-in-webview/8660187)

You cannot determine what webview the JavaScript interface is attached to. Not without doing some preparation upfront. Some options are:

1. Use a different interface name for each webview and then test which one is present to determine which webview you are in.
2. Use the same interface, but have each function in the interface include a parameter called caller which has the number of the calling webview.

Comment: Can I add more than one interface to a single webview? I found out that the context(superclass of activity) I passed into the JSInterface is probably not sufficient enough for getting the webview, since I do need the id of webview.

Comment: You can add as many interfaces as you want to a webview as long as they have different names (e.g. second param to addJavaScriptInterface must be different).

Comment: Ok,I see. Thanks! As you have mentioned before, I can use webview.loadUrl("javascript:") for my callbacks, do you have any examples for that?

Comment: I tried this `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Special Click Was Called');");`, but did not seem work for me.I have put it right below `mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this),"Android");`

Comment: Once you add your "Android" JSInterface to the webview, you can call webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.myjsfunc();"), where myjsfunc is a function implemented in your Java class called JSInterface.

Comment: For that to work you must first make sure that JS is enabled with `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`. For the alert dialog to work you must implement `mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { ... });` in particular the onJsAlert function. In that function you must use AlertDialog.Builder to create the dialog box yourself.

Comment: and one more question, if the callback is just pure js function, I should use mWebVied.loadUrl("javascript:window.myjsfunc();"), right?

Comment: Yes, if you are trying to call a function written in JavaScript, you should use `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.myjsfunc();");`

Answer (score 0):

"You can add as many interfaces as you want to a `WebView` as long as they have different names (e.g. second param to `addJavaScriptInterface` must be different)."

I did not think so. When I try to invoke the second interface. I be told in the `WebChromeClient` that

```
"TypeError: Result of expression 'window.innerJS2' [undefined] is not an object."``
```

The source code as the blow:

```
    webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(innerJavascript, "innerJS");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.innerJS.description();");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(innerJavascript2, "innerJS2");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.innerJS2.description();");
```