# How to disable Android Dialer auto show?

Tags: android, web

I have a web app in jsp/servlet. I don't know why sometimes I touch on an image in webpage, the Android Dialer auto show with the filled contact's numbers such as 72000, 36000 ....
Can you help me solve this problems ?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. Adding this WebKit-specific meta tag worked for me:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Modify the `Webview` specifically. Meaning that you have to take a WebView and override the Methods found in the `WebViewClient` class. This allows your to better control the webview.

Reference:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

This should help:

- [Adding JavaScript Interface to a Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765860/adding-javascript-interface-to-a-browser)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my web app is html,jsp/servlet. How can I solve this problem by javascript ?

Comment: You can use javascript in the webview. However; at this point, you can figure out how the webview parses javascript. Its not very complicated.

Comment: Thank you,but I don't understand your idea.My web app is a mobile website,I'm testing it on android mobile.How can I interact with webview on android by javasript from server side ?

Comment: i'm not expert on javascript, but the android browser supports javascript. Your specific case sounds like you want the server to control  it...

Comment: That's right.My webapp on the server side. Thanks for your replys so much. I don't know where the android dialer can get these number : 7200, 3600 when I touch on an image ?

Comment: The android browser uses a process call linkify where it attempts to parse text as text that can handle specific actions in Android.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will look for an other solution for this problem.