# Adding JavaScript to Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webkit

Can I do something to Android framework (browser/webkit part) to run my own predefined JavaScript (scripts) along with **every** web page browsed by the default web browser of Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765860/adding-javascript-interface-to-a-browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do something to Android framework (browser/webkit part) to run my own predefined JavaScript (scripts) along with every web page browsed by the default web browser of Android?

There is no single "default web browser of Android".

I know of no way to install userscripts on the AOSP Browser or Chrome. There are third-party apps like [TamperMonkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.biniok.tampermonkey&hl=en) that effectively are their own Web browser and offer userscripts, and other third-party browsers may have hooks that could be used for a GreaseMonkey equivalent.

Comment: Just an update for posterity: Android now must have Chrome and the WebView is built on chrome. so most versions of Android now use chrome for the WebView.

Comment: https://openuserjs.org/scripts/eltomjan/UK_Settlement_login_automation/source
You can use better Chrome desktop TamperMonkey plugin in Kiwi and create simple automation page shortcuts like this mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look to this site, i have found very useful the js.
DroidScript provides a JavaScript interface between your HTML pages and native Android code allowing you to utilize device functionality with the simplest of JavaScript commands.

https://github.com/divineprog/droidscript