# how to redirect setting screen in i-phone. when gps is off using phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I have created a mobile app using phonegap,html5 and jquery
in this app
how to redirect setting screen in i-phone when gps is off using phonegap

Comment: what do you mean by redirect setting screen 
you mean change the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

This function gets called when the device is ready with loading your app's content.

So when GPS is disabled on the device it will call the "onError"-Function so the user gets redirected to another screen in your mobile application:

```
function onError(error) {
    window.location.href = 'your-other-html-file.html';
}
```

I hope I got your question right :)

Comment: please gave me code how to redirect setting screen code??  instead of 'your-other-html-file.html'

Comment: Ah kay now I got it...
This may help: [How to redirect towards GPS setting window in android or ios using phonegap for on or off a GPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620140/how-to-redirect-towards-gps-setting-window-in-android-or-ios-using-phonegap-for)

Comment: i implemented but not work proper. please give me full code.. thanks for help.

Comment: Seems that it's impossible on iOS (even when building a native app) - you only can notify the user that GPS is disabled and that he/she has to enable it first.

Comment: You haven't got me... even when writing native iOS code it isn't possible to redirect to iOS settings on an iDevice. So Phonegap apps can't provide this ability too.